# Responsive images using Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As any front dev' I've got a bunch of problem with responsiv images. Trying to make them fit properly any kind of container is some how an hell.

While looking and asking across the web how should I properly do that I have came up with [ImgLiquid](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid). Pretty and efficace. But I'm not really fan of adding plugins and plugins. And because I'm already using Bootstrap I was asking my self if there was a way of doing it with Bootstrap.

I've seen the class `.img-responsive` but it seems not to be very effective.

**So, do you know a way using bootstrap of managing properly responsive image as if I was using ImgLiquid ?**

Just so you can have an idea : This is what I've got using bootstrap :

[image: Example]

Comment: When it has so much features and when its only `< 2.0KBs gzipped` then I don't think there will be any problems using it! Because when bootstrap's solution is not satisfied for you and you expect something better then even if you edit and make it as per your need the size of the file will definitely increase!! Not all the time using plugin is bad is my opinion!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao very true ! I would also let the OP know about the [Perfect background trick using CSS only](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) which is in this example used with a full body background, but also can be used with some responsives div of course !

Comment: Yeah well I'll try with it but moreover I think I have conflict problem. I'll do an other post about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
cal class="width-full"
```

create style

```
<style>
.width-full{width: 100%;}
</style>
```